# Retry failed messages of a Symfony app without the command line

Tags: symfony, symfony-messenger

I have a Symfony 6.2 application that uses the [messenger](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html) component to handle asynchronous messages.

The docs talk about several commands to handle failed messages (messenger:failed:show / messenger:failed:retry / messenger:failed:remove).

However, even though it is an easy way to handle failed messages in a local environment, it becomes complicated when deploying the app to production, where SSH into a server is not an option for these kind of tasks.

Is there a way to create custom code to have some kind of a "fail messages manager"? The endgame would be to build a REST API to handle these.

Comment: Sounds like a job for cron that will periodically call those commands